# How to repeat XSLT child nodes of the same name?

Tags: xslt

I have an xml dump of a transaction that I want to create a report from.
The (simplified) xml structure looks like:

```
Subject
  id
  name
  license
  event id=key
    result
    eventtype
    date
    action
  charge id=key
    result
    code
    date
 ...etc
```

There is only one id, name, and license for every subject; but there could be many events, and many charges for each subject--each one having a different result.

The report output is a table type, with each subject having a header of name, id, license, and multiple blocks of data transactions listed below the header.  Each data block has different values and structure based on the type of transaction.

It works perfectly for the header, and one each of the data transaction types, but only the first event transaction and the first charge transaction will print out.

The (simplified) xsl looks like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="file/subject">
  <xsl:if test="not (@subject = preceding-sibling::subject[1])">
    <table width="754" border="2" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="172">ctn: <strong><xsl:value-of select="id"/></strong></td>
        <td width="364">defendant: <strong><xsl:value-of select="name"/></strong></td>
        <td width="200">sid: <strong><xsl:value-of select="license"/></strong></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:if>
  <blockquote>
    <xsl:if test="event/eventType != ' '">
      <table width="695" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>Event<xsl:value-of select="event/result"/></td>
          <td>Eventtype<xsl:value-of select="event/eventtype"/></td>
          <td>Date<xsl:value-of select="event/date"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="charge/code != ' '">
      <table width="695" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>Charge<xsl:value-of select="charge/result"/></td>
          <td>Code<xsl:value-of select="charge/code"/></td>
          <td>Date<xsl:value-of select="charge/date"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </xsl:if>
  </blockquote>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I assume that I need an additional for-each to scan the child nodes, but adding the additional loop just gives me the headers.

Any thoughts?

(and thanks for taking the time to read this far.  :o)

Comment: Sorry, first time I've tried to use Stack Overflow.  I'll try to get the information I typed to show up correctly.

Comment: I've edited the question to correct the formatting (code samples need four spaces at the start of each line), but you might want to consider a more representative XML sample, rather than just a list of element names. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where possible in XSLT, avoid for-each and apply your nodes to transformation templates instead.

I came up with this, which you can run at [this playground session](http://www.xmlplayground.com/a8PbrS) - not sure if it's broadly what you're after.

```
    <!-- root and static content -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select='root/Subject' />   
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- iteration content: subject -->
    <xsl:template match='Subject'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>ctn: <strong><xsl:value-of select="id"/></strong></td>
                <td>defendant: <strong><xsl:value-of select="name"/></strong></td>
                <td>sid: <strong><xsl:value-of select="license"/></strong></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='event' />
        <xsl:apply-templates select='charge' />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- iteration content: event -->
    <xsl:template match='event'>
        <blockquote>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Event: <xsl:value-of select="result"/></td>
                    <td>Event type: <xsl:value-of select="eventtype"/></td>
                    <td>Date: <xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </blockquote>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- iteration content: charge -->
    <xsl:template match='charge'>
        <blockquote>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Charge: <xsl:value-of select="result"/></td>
                    <td>Code: <xsl:value-of select="code"/></td>
                    <td>Date: <xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </blockquote>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot.  The actual XSL is quite lengthy, so I was hoping to get an answer that confirmed which way I should go before tearing up the current code.  Thank you!

Comment: You could reduce the XSL by deriving the table headings from your XML rather than hard-coding them. That way they could be output dynamically. This would also make it easier to come up with a solution for transforming both `event` and `charge` nodes via the same template, rather than, as currently, separate ones.

Comment: Thank you.  That hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider accepting the answer *if* it solved your problem, or at least up-voting if it partially helped.